# How to share my whole Google Agendas to someone who is on iCal or Outlook

Tags: calendar

I search the most handy solution to allow my partner to see all my agenda, who uses iCal on iPhone and on a Mac at home, while I am using a Gmail account, on an Android or on my PC.

I can share my personnal gmail calendar, but I'm also in *other* work groups that use a google shared agenda.

I would like that my partner is able to see all the events that I can myself see, at the very least (no need to be able to add or edit anything).

Additional info : for work, my partner also uses outlook on a daily basis, if that could allow an alternative solution.

Is there a free app for this, that kind of aggregates calendars as one calendar to share ?"